# how to add new value to a Label , without reassign the Label to a new variabel?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

i am want to create a button that shows you how many times you have pressed it while you are pressing it.

But i don't know how to "refresh" it everytime it's pressed .

Can someone help me ?

```
from tkinter import *


class Press():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.scale = self.root.wm_minsize(width=500, height=300)
        self.changer = StringVar()
        self.changer.set(0)

        self.label = Label(self.root , textvariable= self.changer)

        self.button = Button(self.root, text="PRESS", command= self.amount_pressed)


        self.button.pack()
        self.label.pack()
        self.mainloop = mainloop()

    def amount_pressed(self):
        self.changer.set(+1)

test = Press()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *


class Press():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.scale = self.root.wm_minsize(width=500, height=300)
        self.changer = StringVar()
        self.changer.set(0)

        self.label = Label(self.root , textvariable= self.changer)

        self.button = Button(self.root, text="PRESS", command= self.amount_pressed)


        self.button.pack()
        self.label.pack()
        self.mainloop = mainloop()

    def amount_pressed(self):
        self.changer.set(int(self.changer.get()) + 1)

test = Press()
```

Explanation:

By using `self.changer.set(+1)`, you are setting `self.changer` to a **positive one** (as opposed to **adding one** to it).

What you want to do is:

- get the string value of `self.changer`
- convert it to an integer
- add 1 to it

So:

`self.changer.set(int(self.changer.get()) + 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the help . It worked , i just got into tkinter and thanks for the explanation it helped aswell .

Comment: Great! Some further explanation, in case it helps in the future: tkinter labels don't use normal Python variables types. Instead, they use tcl types, such as `StringVar`. to get the values of such variables, you can call their `.get()` method, which returns a python variable. Now you can convert, change and use it as you like :)